# unable to resolve static field

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I downloaded code from [this repo](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView), and create a project for it, and copy all source code to the new project.

The new project build successfully.

The project contains two modules sample and library:

Module library contains some class and a few resource id

Module sample depends on library. When run the app on device, it crashes with exception:

```
W/dalvikvm(13442): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5319 (expandable_toggle_button) in Lcom/tjerkw/slideexpandable/library/R$id;
D/dalvikvm(13442): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm(13442): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x14c6 at 0x02 in Lcom/tjerkw/slideexpandable/library/SlideExpandableListAdapter;.<init>
D/AndroidRuntime(13442): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(13442): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c75da0)
E/AndroidRuntime(13442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13442): Process: com.lxj.testslideexpandablelistview, PID: 13442
E/AndroidRuntime(13442): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.library.R$id
E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.library.SlideExpandableListAdapter.<init>(SlideExpandableListAdapter.java:25)
E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.library.SlideExpandableListView.setAdapter(SlideExpandableListView.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.library.ActionSlideExpandableListView.setAdapter(ActionSlideExpandableListView.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(13442):    at com.tjerkw.slideexpandable.sample.ExampleActivity.onCreate(ExampleActivity.java:35)
```

I extract+decompile the apk file, and find the resource id is there, but with different value:

```
public static final int expandable_toggle_button = 2131230725;
```

How to solve it? I search around the internet, all the articles are referring to Eclipse, but I am using Android Studio. Can anybody give help? Thanks.

The root build.gradle is this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The library build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lxj.slideexpandablelistview"
//        minSdkVersion 11
//        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            runProguard false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
    //    }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

The sample build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lxj.testslideexpandablelistview"
//        minSdkVersion 11
//        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            runProguard false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
//    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile project(':library')
}
```